# Witcher 3 experience when everything is grayed out

Tags: the-witcher-3

I'm level 26. I'm playing until around level 29 before starting the Isle Of Mist and finish the game.

All quests except two are grayed because they are for level below 15.

The two quests above 26 are for level 30 to 33.

Where am I suppose to get experience to level up if there are no quests to be done?

I think I won't gain level fast enough by killing small monsters in the forest.

Is there a better way to level up without quests?

Comment: all quests? do you mean all contracts and treasure hunts too?

Comment: Maybe a tip if you ever restart the game. Make sure you get all quests as soon as possible in your log by going to every yellow icon on the map as soon as possible. And when doing them do the from low to high level. That way you prevent quests from ever getting gray making them give you more xp in the long run.

Comment: @lokuzt , not ALL quests. But I'm near the end of the game (level 27 at this point) and I have been nearly everywhere in the map. So, I have read many quest boards and I have something around 20 missions, all gray.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you mentioned quests. When I was playing Witcher 3 I was higher leveled than that for the Isle Of Mist. And I didn't do all the contracts or treasure hunts.

**So basically do more contracts, do more treasure hunts and explore the "question marks" on the map.**

You will get a lot of experience from these things.

EDIT: Do the grayed out missions anyway and get some XP.

If you want to be sneaky beaky and get XP on demand you can add the Dev Commands Mod ([here](http://www.nexusmods.com/witcher3/mods/143/?))

But if I were I would leave that as ultimate last resort

Comment: The problem is that I'm way too higher than the quests available in my list... and I have traveled a lot of the map... so it's becoming REALLY hard to find a mission around level 27. Missions below 23 or 22 are all gray (nearly no experience) and missions left are all red (too difficult for my level).

Comment: I guess I will just travel to some of those question marks and see what I can find... maybe kill some monsters in skellie island. But thanks for the tips!

Comment: Trust me do those. A lot of them give good XP.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that you're already overleveled for that particular main quest. The Isle of Mists is a level 22 quest, you're not really supposed to get to level 29 before doing it. I'm just about to do this quest in my second playthrough now, and I'm at the end of level 24. I skipped a few side quests, but not many.

One way the game tries to prevent players from overleveling by doing all the side quests is that the amount of XP you get from main quests is drastically higher than the XP you get from side quests. This makes a huge difference, and your level is mostly determined by how many main quests you already did, and not so much by the side quests.

The Isle of Mists is also not the end of the game, I won't spoiler anything here, but I'd suggest to stop worrying and just doing this quest. There's still plenty of game afterwards.

Comment: I already tried that mission and couldn't kill that big guy. That's why i am trying to level up.

Comment: @vianna77 You'll get much more out of some better alchemy items or general equipment than from a level or two. Just craft the best equipment you can and upgrade all potions and oils.